# Gatsby + WooCommerce REST API integration?

Tags: woocommerce, gatsby

I'm a bit new to Gatsby, React and GraphQL, so I just wanted to check with the community before heading down the wrong road...

Would the WooCommerce REST API (via the WordPress REST API) be a possible e-commerce integration for Gatsby? If so, can the WooCommerce API be queried using GraphQL (similar to querying the WordPress REST API using the gatsby-source-wordpress plugin)? Can this all be accomplished simply by using the WordPress REST API?

If anyone has integrated WooCommerce with Gatsby (or knows of a Gatsby e-commerce solution that works even better), I'd love to know about it!

Answer (score 2):

As of version 2.6 WooCommerce is fully integrated with the Wordpress REST API. Wordpress added a REST API to its core build starting from v4.4.

In short, yes, you can certainly use gatsby-source-wordpress plugin to generate product, tag and category pages. However, attempting to merge a static site with a dynamically generated one can prove challenging.

My understanding is that you wish to use the cart and checkout features of Woocommerce and statically serve content pages at the same time. That would be daunting task, but doable nevertheless given you make certain strategic decisions about your site's overall structure.

Comment: Great point! I hadn't thought about the difficulty of blending dynamic e-commerce features with a statically generated site. I'm new to React and Gatsby and had just assumed I could use Gatsby for everything.

Comment: By the way, can you suggest how to properly structure a Gatsby site to use the WooCommerce cart and checkout features?

Comment: gatsby is static, so unless your checkout is fully client side, it's impossible to do it (because, well, checkouts pages arn't in anyway static!) Of course you can manage it clientside, but you still need some backend to handle payments and other things in a secure way.